# Elaticsearch Sink Kafka Connector fails with ConnectionClosedException

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are running a Confluent ElasticsearchSinkConnector on a dedicated K8S Kafka connect cluster, all seems to be working well and records appears on our Elasticsearch cluster.
Once in a while we are getting an unrecoverable error, which fails that task(s) and require a manual restart of the connector(s).

There are not much details regarding the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Bulk request failed
     due to 
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
```

We are running with the following configurations:

```
Class:  io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
  Config:
    batch.size:                       1000
    behavior.on.malformed.documents:  warn
    behavior.on.null.values:          delete
    connection.compression:           true
    connection.password:              my-password
    connection.timeout.ms:            30000
    connection.url:                   https://es-http.com:9200
    connection.username:              elastic
    errors.log.enable:                true
    errors.log.include.messages:      true
    errors.tolerance:                 all
    key.converter:                    org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    read.timeout.ms:                  30000
    retry.backoff.ms:                 60000
    schema.ignore:                    true
    Topics:                           my-topic
    Transforms:                       ExtractField
    transforms.ExtractField.field:    metadata
    transforms.ExtractField.type:     org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value
    value.converter:                  org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter.schemas.enable:   false
  Tasks Max:                          10
```

We are running a 3 nodes Elasticsearch cluster from this image: `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0`, not sure if it is relevant.

There is no extra logs on neither the Elasticsearch cluster nor on the Kafka connect cluster.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit the log4j level to be debug or trace